# database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode MULTIPLE DATABASES

Tags: android, sqlite, multiple-databases

I am creating a SDK that is implemented by client app, the client app has it's own DB. I create and access my DB using the client app's `application context`.

I have used a `Singleton Pattern` for my `SQLOpenHelper` and made sure access to it is through a `synchronised` method.

The client app still gets

```
database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:896)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:641)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:323)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:297)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:218)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:196)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:836)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:821)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:714)
   at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:592)
   at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:280)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
```

1. Can someone please tell me why this crash could be happening?
2. Can it be because of simultaneous access to the Client DB as well as my DB?
3. Does a common SQLiteOpenHelper instance is provided for client as well as my app?

Thanks for help in advance!!!